# Tracing Celery tasks in Django with AWS X-Ray

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, celery, django-celery, aws-xray

I'm trying to get traces from Celery tasks in my Django application. I'm using X-Ray from AWS. I am getting traces for normal HTTP calls, SQL database queries, but not for Celery tasks or Redis. The log statements in the implemented tasks are available in X-Ray.
In my `AppConfig` implementation I've done the usual:

```
from aws_xray_sdk.core import patch_all
patch_all()
from aws_xray_sdk.core import xray_recorder
# Need a default segment to avoid issues when running migrations and other management commands
xray_recorder.begin_segment("migrations")
```

How should I go about it to get traces from Celery tasks and Redis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present X-Ray SDK does not support Celery and Redis

Comment: Aha! How do you know?